# Api Яндекс.Карт неправильно определяет район

Tags: xmlhttprequest, yandex-geocoding-api

Определяю район с помощью геокодера Яндекс.Карт, таким [запросом](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&kind=district&geocode=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8).

На такой метод определения координат ссылается эта [запись](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/51172) в Клубу Api Карт

Этот метод работает правильно по многим районам ЮЗАО, которые я тестировал, но почему-то неправильно именно в Теплом Стане. Там вместо района Москвы "Теплый Стан", возвращается микрорайон.

Вот, [пример](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&kind=district&geocode=37.514275%2055.633622).
Я беру всегда из гео-коллекции первый гео-объект и оттуда name. С другими районами проходит, а с Теплым Станом нет. Тут уже во втором объекте в name правильное названием района.

Как быть? Я всегда рассчитывал на первый объект, а теперь оказывается, есть исключения. Как тогда правильно выбирать объект, чтобы определить район по координатам? Не перебирать же каждый, пока не встретится правильное название?

Answer (score 1):

В Геокодере к компоненту `district` относятся городские округа, районы и микрорайоны. Точка `37.514275, 55.633622` находится на территории микрорайона, поэтому полный адрес в ответе содержит 3 компонента `district`:

```
{
kind: "district",
name: "Юго-Западный административный округ"
},
{
kind: "district",
name: "район Тёплый Стан"
},
{
kind: "district",
name: "1-4-й микрорайон"
}
```

Микрорайоны есть не везде, поэтому точка вне микрорайона будет содержать 2 компонента `district`, например:

```
{
kind: "district",
name: "Восточный административный округ"
},
{
kind: "district",
name: "район Северное Измайлово"
}
```

Возможно, что *только для Москвы* можно считать, что район будет в предпоследнем результате - иерархия ответов Геокодера строится по релевантности от самого точного соответствия (более маленький объект), то есть при запросе с `kind=district` вы получаете в первом результате микрорайон, если он есть, а в самом последнем - округ. Но вообще говоря, такое поведение не гарантируется в документации и завязываться на это стоит на свой страх и риск.

Comment: То есть можно ориентироваться на предпоследний результат, но надежнее проверять содержится ли в ответе слово "район" вместо "микрорайон" или "округ"?

Comment: Получается, что так)